# Loop through variables in Dask using Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dask

Good afternoon.

I am encountering a slight hiccup in Dask. I'm fairly new to Dask (in Python) and I'd like to run parallelized ML models using pure Dask (as opposed to dask-ml) based on the variable named 'class'. I wish to know what the predicted outcome of the model will be as I vary feature1 (as, in my data, I know this is the most significant one). I run my computing on a 4-node cluster and save all the predicted for all classes in `predicted_all`.

Here's an example of my pandas data df:

```
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+---+-------------+
| class | target |  feature1   |  feature2   | … |  feature10  |
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+---+-------------+
| A     |      5 | 97.19859896 | 816.6842211 | … | 0.54895439  |
| A     |      6 | 46.09606585 | 784.3270075 | … | 8.251889349 |
| A     |     43 | 17.65188263 | 549.5501609 | … | 13.50763389 |
| A     |      2 | 98.85817622 | 708.1968399 | … | 7.621150619 |
| A     |     56 | 88.01917025 | 613.0401243 | … | 6.000443628 |
| B     |      4 | 70.80513786 | 906.0185026 | … | 19.41657943 |
| B     |     78 | 93.80801173 | 891.289798  | … | 8.501099853 |
| B     |      7 | 46.63101139 | 483.0638367 | … | 3.875892614 |
| B     |      1 | 67.5788966  | 743.5923161 | … | 8.671806546 |
| B     |      0 | 90.90392867 | 109.8205978 | … | 17.70970394 |
| …     |        | …           | …           | … | …           |
| Z     |     89 | 58.424834   | 794.9165579 | … | 17.51302389 |
| Z     |    854 | 58.21094669 | 714.8873807 | … | 3.334251242 |
| Z     |     25 | 75.5155099  | 61.59911771 | … | 8.507249536 |
| Z     |     90 | 47.13722692 | 861.3884932 | … | 11.95500215 |
| Z     |     52 | 9.824626526 | 528.1958297 | … | 10.10468804 |
+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+---+-------------+
```

df is a pandas dataframe onto which I'd like to run a loop so that dask parallelizes the work on each node whilst using pandas dataframe.

As per the Dask tutorials, I do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

classes = ['ABC...Z']
predicted_all = pd.DataFrame()

def linearmodel(class): #application of linear regression on data

    global predicted_all
    df_oneClass = df[df['class'] == class].drop(['class'], axis=1)
    df_y = pd.DataFrame(df_oneClass['target'])
    df_X = df_oneClass.drop(['target'], axis=1)

    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(df_X, df_y)

    X_predict = [] ## range of feature1 values I'd like to know the forecast outcome for
    y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
    predicted_all = pd.concat([predicted_all, y_predict], axis = 0

results = [delayed(linearmodel)(class) for class in classes]
resultsDask = compute(*results, get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
```

As per MRocklin's suggestion, I did a re-write and I focus on getting the Mean Absolute Errors of each class iteration and create a tuple. My function is now as follows:

```
def linearmodel(class): #application of linear regression on data

    df_oneClass = df[df['class'] == class].drop(['class'], axis=1)
    df_y = pd.DataFrame(df_oneClass['target'])
    df_X = df_oneClass.drop(['target'], axis=1)

    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(df_X, df_y)

    y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
    mae = mean_absolute_error(df_y, y_predict)

    return (class, mae)

results = [delayed(linearmodel)(class) for class in classes]
resultsDask = compute(*results, get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
```

Unfortunately, the work is not parallelized and predicted_all is empty. Any clues as to why please?

Thanks for taking the time to read this and any help or pointers are more than welcome.

Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using global state and instead use functions that return values directly.

Comment: Ok great! Thanks. Will try that instead and report back.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I re-wrote the initial code and put the edited version in the initial question. I now focus on the MAE whilst getting a tuple out of the computation. I'm still not getting any parallelization across the worker nodes. Only the master node is performing the computing. Anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks again Christian

Comment: It works!!! Thanks. Sorry forgot to launch 
'from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client('xxxxx')'
Thanks again for the help!
Christian